# Using solved reCAPTCHA to scrape a redirect with Python Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, redirect, python-requests, recaptcha

I am trying to scrape a page using Python Requests. https://isoms.lasallecounty.org/portal/Jail is intercepted with a reCAPTCHA page (https://isoms.lasallecounty.org/portal/imahuman). In a manual test, upon completing this reCAPTCHA there is a POST using a `g-recaptcha-response` and a `__RequestVerificationToken` which redirects to the initial URL and allows a successful request.

I am using anti-captcha to successfully collect the `g-recaptcha-response` param and BeautifulSoup to collect the verification token, but I am unsure how to use these to then successfully collect the redirected jail page.

Including commented code below; the final request, whether made to the /imahuman or to the /Jail URL, and whether made with or without `allow_redirects=True`, fails.

```
# make an initial request and collect verification token
headers = {
            "Referer": "https://isoms.lasallecounty.org/portal/imahuman",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
        }
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get("https://isoms.lasallecounty.org/portal/Jail")  # redirects to /portal/imahuman
token = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml").find("input", {"name": "__RequestVerificationToken"})["value"]
site_key = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml").find("div", {"id": "recaptcha"})["data-sitekey"]

# anticaptcha solver
solver = recaptchaV3Proxyless()
solver.set_verbose(1)
solver.set_key(os.getenv("ANTICAPTCHA_API_KEY"))
solver.set_website_url("https://isoms.lasallecounty.org/portal/imahuman")
solver.set_website_key(site_key)
solver.set_min_score(0.9)
g_response = solver.solve_and_return_solution()
if g_response != 0:
    print("success!")
else:
    print("task finished with error " + solver.error_code)
        
# plug everything in params dict
data = {
            "g-recaptcha-response": g_response,
            "__RequestVerificationToken": token
        }

# try to post imahuman page 
response = session.post("https://isoms.lasallecounty.org/portal/imahuman", headers=headers, data=data, allow_redirects=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Examine the POST the the server when it redirects, if your using the same user agent, you should be able to create a custom https package and ship that off with the same user-agent. You could also run a web scrapping library with the option to run with the browser open, then you could do the captcha yourself and then tell the program to continue with a key input.

Comment: So far as I can see I'm using the correct User-Agent (line 4 in the code snippet above)... I could do this with Selenium and a driver for instance, but I'd rather complete it simply with requests if that's an option.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).